# pass function in object ignores function parameters on execution

Tags: javascript, function

I am passing the following object to a custom hook (I am using react but this question should not be react specific). The object is created in a file called `Login.js` - Please note the `console.log` statements:

```
const requestConfig = {
  url : "http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth",
  method : "POST",
  headers : { "Content-Type" : "application/json"},
  body: {
      email : email,
      password : password,
      service_type : "login",
  },
  onSuccessFunction : (responseJSON) => {
      console.log("Login.js.onSuccessFunction: JSON.stringify(responseJSON): ###" + JSON.stringify(responseJSON) + "###");
      console.log("Login.js.onSuccessFunction: responseJSON: " + responseJSON);
      if(responseJSON.result === "success") {
          const accessToken = responseJSON.access_token;
          dispatch(authActions.login({ accessToken : accessToken }));
      }
      console.log("Login.js.onSuccessFunction: Done");
  },
};
sendRequest(requestConfig);
```

I am using the following implementation in a file called `useHttp.js` (Also, please note the `console.log` statements):

```
  const sendRequest = async (requestConfig) => {
    setResponseJSON({});
    try {
        const response = await fetch(requestConfig.url, {
            method: requestConfig.method ? requestConfig.method : "GET",
            body: requestConfig.body ? JSON.stringify(requestConfig.body) : null,
            headers: requestConfig.headers ? requestConfig.headers : {}
        });
        if(!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(response.status+"");
        }
        const responseJson = await response.json();
        if(requestConfig.onSuccessFunction) {
            console.log("useHttp.onSuccessFunction - BEGIN");
            console.log("useHttp - JSON.stringify(responseJson)" + JSON.stringify(responseJson));
            console.log("useHttp typeof requestConfig.onSuccessFunction: " + (typeof requestConfig.onSuccessFunction)); 
            requestConfig.onSuccessFunction(responseJSON);
            console.log("useHttp.onSuccessFunction - END");
        }
        setResponseJSON(responseJson);
    } catch(err) {
        setResponseJSON({
            result: "error",
            message: "Error: " + err.message
        });
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
```

Now when I run this code I get the following output in the console:

```
useHttp.onSuccessFunction - BEGIN
useHttp - JSON.stringify(responseJson){"access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0b20udmFuY2tAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjQwNjI1NDgyLCJleHAiOjE2NDA2MjU0OTJ9.0e0Zx7E6llmEtu2AAxIT61xSxE_jffgq81EDNRefURI","result":"success"}
useHttp typeof requestConfig.onSuccessFunction: function
Login.js.onSuccessFunction: JSON.stringify(responseJSON): ###""###
Login.js.onSuccessFunction: responseJSON: 
Login.js.onSuccessFunction: Done
useHttp.onSuccessFunction - END
```

As you can see I am passing a `onSuccessFunction` within the `requestConfig` object and it is correctly reported as a `function` in `console.log("useHttp typeof requestConfig.onSuccessFunction: " + (typeof requestConfig.onSuccessFunction));`.

However, why the hack is the parameter `responseJSON` not passed to `onSuccessFunction` when `onSuccessFunction` is executed? Where did `responseJSON` go?

Comment: shouldn't it be `responseJson` not `responseJSON` ?

Comment: OMG, you are right... Thanks! Man, why don't you get an error when executing this like with any other programming language... the browser just runs through without any warning. JS is just a pain in the a...